# How to determine if NULL is contained in an array in Postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

How do I determine if NULL is contained in an array in Postgres? Currently using Postgres 9.3.3.

If I test with the following select it returns `contains_null = false`.

```
select ARRAY[NULL,1,2,3,4,NULL]::int[] @> ARRAY[NULL]::int[] AS contains_null
select ARRAY[NULL,1,2,3,4,NULL]::int[] @> NULL AS contains_null
```

I've also tried with:

1. @> (contains)
2. <@ (is contained by)
3. && (overlap)

Comment: More solutions under this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472

Comment: `create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', null);
select * from scientist where lastname is null or lastname in ('einstein', 'newton', null);`. I tried this, but the select query didnt' return the `null` entry here. So, I think, this is how it works, a `null` in the array won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select exists (
    select 1 
    from unnest(array[1, null]) s(a)
    where a is null
);
 exists 
--------
 t
```

Or shorter:

```
select bool_or(a is null)
from unnest(array[1, null]) s(a)
;
 bool_or 
---------
 t
```

Comment: is there a better way than using unnest? I've thought about that but with 1+ million records with a column that could have 30+ array items, unnest produces quite a few records. It's an audit table.

Comment: @thames I think the unnest will perform well and I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 16):

One more construction, like @Clodoaldo Neto proposed. Just more compact expression:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE null_arrays (
      id serial primary key
    , array_data int[]
);

INSERT INTO null_arrays (array_data)
VALUES
      (ARRAY[1,2, NULL, 4, 5])
    , (ARRAY[1,2, 3, 4, 5])
    , (ARRAY[NULL,2, 3, NULL, 5])
;

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    null_arrays
WHERE
    TRUE = ANY (SELECT unnest(array_data) IS NULL)
;
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems the following works fine in PostgreSQL 10.1.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    ...
    my_set  int[] NOT NULL,
    ...
);

SELECT
    my_set
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    array_position(my_set, NULL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 7):

Ideally you'd write:

```
SELECT
    NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ANY ARRAY[NULL,1,2,3,4,NULL]::int[];
```

but the parser doesn't recognise `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` as valid syntax for an operator here, and I can't find an operator alias for it.

You'd have to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION opr_isnotdistinctfrom(anyelement, anyelement)
RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS $$
SELECT $1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $2; 
$$;

CREATE OPERATOR <<>> (
    PROCEDURE = opr_isnotdistinctfrom,
    LEFTARG = anyelement,
    RIGHTARG = anyelement
);

SELECT NULL <<>> ANY (ARRAY[NULL,1,2,3,4,NULL]::int[]);
```

which seems a bit gruesome, but should optimize out just fine.

Answer (score 4):

i didn't want to use `unnest` either, so i used a comparison of `array_length` using `array_remove` to solve a similar problem.  Tested on 9.4.1, but should work in 9.3.3.

```
SELECT
ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY[1,null], 1) > ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY[1,null], NULL), 1) 
OR ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY[1,null], NULL), 1) IS NULL
---------
t
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT array_position(ARRAY[1,2,3,NULL], NULL)
```

returns 4 (position of NULL)
returns NULL if element not found

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as a reuseable function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_check_no_null (anyarray)
  RETURNS bool LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
 'SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN array_position($1, NULL) IS NULL END';
```

You can then use it in a check constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  array_with_no_nulls TEXT[] NOT NULL CHECK(f_check_no_null(array_with_no_nulls))
);
```