# How do I get the type of an array's elements?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, polymorphism, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I'm writing a **polymorphic** PL/pgSQL function that iterates over an array. I am interested in using `FOREACH`, however I cannot figure out how to declare a temporary variable with the right type.

My function is below, for more information see the comment on line 4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniq(ary anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
DECLARE
  ret ary%TYPE := '{}';
  v ???; -- how do I get the element type of @ary@?
BEGIN
  IF ary IS NULL THEN
    return NULL;
  END IF;

  FOREACH v IN ARRAY ary LOOP
    IF NOT v = any(ret) THEN
      ret = array_append(ret, v);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer to primary question

AFAIK, you cannot declare a variable of a polymorphic type *without* a "template" variable or parameter.

There are related examples in the manual at the end of the chapter [Declaring Function Parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS), but ***this* trick** is not covered: add another `IN`, `INOUT` or `OUT` parameter with data type `ANYELEMENT` to the function definition. It resolves to the matching element type automatically and can be (ab)used as variable inside the function body directly or as template for more variables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniq1(ary ANYARRAY, v ANYELEMENT = NULL)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
DECLARE
   ret      ary%TYPE := '{}';
   some_var v%TYPE;  -- we could declare more variables now
                     -- but we don't need to
BEGIN
   IF ary IS NULL THEN
      RETURN NULL;
   END IF;

   FOREACH v IN ARRAY ary LOOP  -- instead, we can use v directly
      IF NOT v = any(ret) THEN
         ret := array_append(ret, v);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN ret;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)

Copying types like that only works in the `DECLARE` section and is different type casting. [It is explained in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE)

Assign a default value, so the added parameter does not have to be included in the function call: `ANYELEMENT`**`= NULL`**

Call (unchanged):

```
SELECT uniq1('{1,2,1}'::int[]);
SELECT uniq1('{foo,bar,bar}'::text[]);
```

#### Better function

I would actually use an OUT parameter for convenience and invert the test logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniq2(ary ANYARRAY, elem ANYELEMENT = NULL
                               , OUT ret ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF ary IS NULL
      THEN RETURN;
      ELSE ret := '{}';  -- init
   END IF;

   FOREACH elem IN ARRAY ary LOOP
      IF elem = ANY(ret) THEN  -- do nothing
      ELSE
         ret := array_append(ret, elem);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this still does not cover all cases containing NULL elements.

#### Proper function

To work for NULL elements as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniq3(ary ANYARRAY, elem ANYELEMENT = NULL
                               , OUT ret ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS anyarray AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF ary IS NULL
      THEN RETURN;
      ELSE ret := '{}';  -- init
   END IF;

   FOREACH elem IN ARRAY ary LOOP
      IF elem IS NULL THEN  -- special test for NULL
         IF array_length(array_remove(ret, NULL), 1) = array_length(ret, 1) THEN
            ret := array_append(ret, NULL);
         END IF;
      ELSIF elem = ANY(ret) THEN  -- do nothing
      ELSE
         ret := array_append(ret, elem);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Checking for NULL in an array is a bit of a pain:

- [How to determine if NULL is contained in an array in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695015/how-to-determine-if-null-is-contained-in-an-array-in-postgres/28460247#28460247)

All of these functions are **just proof of concept**. I would use **neither**. Instead:

### Superior solutions with plain SQL

In Postgres 9.4 use `WITH ORDINALITY` to preserve original order of elements.
Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Basic code for single value:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT elem
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (elem) elem, i
      FROM   unnest('{1,2,1,NULL,4,NULL}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, i)
      ORDER  BY elem, i
      ) sub
   ORDER  BY i) AS uniq;
```

Returns:

```
uniq
------------
{1,2,NULL,4}
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Built into a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT elem
      FROM  (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (elem) elem, i
         FROM   unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, i)
         ORDER  BY elem, i
         ) sub
      ORDER BY i) AS arr
   ) a;
```

This has a tiny corner case: it returns an empty array a NULL array. To cover all bases:

```
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN t.arr IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE a.arr END AS arr
FROM   test t
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT elem
      FROM  (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (elem) elem, ord
         FROM   unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, ord)
         ORDER  BY elem, ord
         ) sub
      ORDER BY ord) AS arr
   ) a;
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT elem
      FROM  (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (elem) elem, i
         FROM   unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, i)
         ORDER  BY elem, i
         ) sub
      ORDER BY i) AS arr
   ) a ON t.arr IS NOT NULL;
```

In **Postgres 9.3** or older you can substitute with `generate_subscripts()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT elem
      FROM  (
         SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.arr[i]) t.arr[i] AS elem, i
         FROM   generate_subscripts(t.arr, 1) i
         ORDER  BY t.arr[i], i
         ) sub
      ORDER  BY i
      ) AS arr
   ) a;
```

We need this in sqlfiddle, which currently only supports pg 9.3, so `WITH ORDINALITY` is not available:

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07650/1)

Comment: I like the WITH ORDINALITY part. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: really nice answer, i was looking for the same but couldn't find it anywhere else, it would be great if you can provide document link from where you got this--- > variable%TYPE.  also it only works into declaration of variable i tried the same for typecasting but it didn't work

Comment: @abhirathore2006: I added a link to the manual for `%TYPE` above. Typecasting is a different beast altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to declare a variable of base type of an `anyarray` argument ([the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) makes no mention of such a possibility).

You can use `FOR LOOP` with integer variable instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniq(ary anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
DECLARE
  ret ary%TYPE := '{}';
  i int;
BEGIN
  IF ary IS NULL THEN
    return NULL;
  END IF;

  FOR i IN array_lower(ary, 1) .. array_upper(ary, 1) LOOP
    IF NOT ary[i] = any(ret) THEN
      ret = array_append(ret, ary[i]);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN ret;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, loops and variables may not be necessary:

```
create or replace function uniq_without_loop(arr anyarray)
returns anyarray language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return (
        select array_agg(distinct elem)
        from unnest(arr) elem);
end $$;
```

The version of the above function that leaves the array order unchanged:

```
create or replace function unsorted_uniq_without_loop(arr anyarray)
returns anyarray language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return (
        select array_agg(elem)
        from (
            select elem 
            from (
                select distinct on(elem) elem, row_number() over ()
                from unnest(array[arr]) elem
                ) sub
            order by row_number
            ) sub);
end $$;
```

Comment: I've tried your second solution. The problem is that the data I'm using must maintain order, but your second solution messes up order.

Comment: Interestingly enough, someone submitted a patch just before version 9.4 of Postgres was frozen for release that implements `arr%elemtype`.

Comment: I've added the version that doesn't sort the result. The idea of this special type makes sense.